# why i am getting error while creating Controller/Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a new app named Useremail, but on terminal when I'm creating controller/model, it's throwing an error and not generating controller/model.

> ac@ac-HP:~/Useremail$ bin/rails g controller Users
>
> /home/ac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in
> `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active
> Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3
> (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0.
>
> Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)

Comment: make sure you run `bundle install` and then `bundle update` and try that

Comment: Show your database.yml

Comment: Thank you, Harsh, i updated gemfile ( mentioned the version for the gem 'sqlite3' as gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6' and then run bundle install) which was suggested by Ragavi and issue has solved. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your project Gemfile, mention the version for the gem 'sqlite3' as gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

Then bundle install

Comment: hi Ragavi, firstly thankyou so much, i followed what you have mention in your answer and the issue has been solved. now i am able to create controller and model. Thank you once again

Comment: Welcome Ayush!!

Comment: @Ayush Mark it as accepted if answer solved problem.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same problem. This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: while this works, I'd love to understand why this is necessary given you're scaffolding a new project

Comment: @StevenGrant gem sqlite3 1.4.0 was released two days ago, which is installed by default. The new version may have some bug, which will probably be fixed soon

Comment: @StevenGrant check for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54530147/10522579) which have **reference** also