# replace_gem: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter - while creating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting an error while creating a model in the created project and the error is as follows,

> /home/sushmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)

Comment: run `bundle` in you're project directory and then try creating models.

Comment: @ray thank you it worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For reference only following is added here,

For `Rails 5+`, this issue is sort out by specifying the appropriate version for the `sqlite` gem in your `Gemfile` while working with an `SQLite` database:

```
 gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.6'
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d9601fd622a08b8ef5346c10f00fb13328d34d76#diff-1b086e9c0c1a6b852fda7b3542d6957b)

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work? Same exact error, Rails 5+, but solution didn't work for me. Brand new application. Just basically ran `rails new app_name` and `rails g scaffold ModelName name:text`

Comment: At least up until rails 5.2.2 this should be `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'`. Specifying `'~> 1.3'` as well will allow sqlite3 1.4 which will only be supported by rails 5.2.3. @ray gave the correct version specification in his comment above. Please also see (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564000/3206935)

Answer (score 18):

For rails 5.2.2 explicitly , update your Gemfile to sqlite to:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

and in terminal use :

```
bundle update
```

Comment: Why? Where is this documented?

Comment: @andrewcockerham I exactly don't remember where I saw that , I'm too a newbie , tried different versions and got on this one.

Comment: Every time I switched back to rails after some time, it surprises me in different ways

Answer (score 1):

I have placed `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'` inside of `group :deevelopment, :test do` and it worked for me.

e.g :

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that [rails 5.2.2.1 has been released](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/3/13/Rails-4-2-5-1-5-1-6-2-have-been-released/), the correct and also easiest fix is to bump rails to that version, as it will restrict sqlite3 to `1.3.6`:

```rb
# In Gemfile
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2.1'
```

And then in the terminal

```
bundle install
```

Given the security fixes in that version, this should be done anyway.