# Ruby can't loading the 'sqlite3'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

While loading server, got following error

> /home/othmane/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please make sure to format your question appropriately, it is hard to read, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54529739/10522579)

Comment: You are using `ruby-2.6.0` (indicated in error log) for `rails-3` ?