# Build new Rails app Error loading the 'sqlite3' without evidently write verion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rvm, bundler

When generate new rails app, and start the server "rails s", first massage I got:

> Puma caught this error: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)

after reload a page:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
>   No connection pool with 'primary' found.

```
  def retrieve_connection(spec_name) #:nodoc:
    pool = retrieve_connection_pool(spec_name)
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found." unless pool
    pool.connection
  end
```

I reinstall ruby, rails, bundler, all except rvm
and I don't know what to do

P.S.
this error disappears when I evidently write sqlite3 verion, but it should work fine from a without it!!!
Help!What to do? or maybe reinstall all of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brand new rails app, can't generate scaffold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563777/brand-new-rails-app-cant-generate-scaffold)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to add this on your Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

Instead of having only the SQLite3 without version.

It worked for me

Comment: yes, i know it
it work for me too
but...it is not a solution of problem
is stupid to make some changes in new app, which should work without any changes

Comment: @Axelrod, but that is a problem that only the rails team will be able to fix. And actually there is already a commit fixing it in the 5.2 branch but 5.2.3 would need to be released before it becomes available by default.

Comment: @ulferts
okay, another idea how about to reinstall all? I try to but I have feeling than smth may stay....so it didn't help how do it right?

Comment: @Axelrod, you currently cannot work around the need to limit the sqlite3 gem to stay within the 1.3 range. Removing and reinstalling won't help there. But as soon as it is specified, a call to `bundle install` will solve the problem.

Comment: @ulferts no, it didn't help

Answer (score 4):

To me, edit your Gemfile:

> gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

and run this command:

> bundle install

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by adding sqlite3 version in the Gemfile.